# how to increment a char in assembly pic18f4550?

Tags: assembly, pic

I'm writing a program in pic assembly for the pic18f4550 that counts the number of cars passing through a sensor and i will display the value on the LCD. the values sent to an LCD are of type char. My problem is that i can't figure out how to increment my variable which is the number of cars passing knowing that it is a char.

Comment: It is a `char` or `char`-s?

Comment: `char` is a C type. The assembly language for the pic18 knows only raw bytes. The `INCF` instruction can be used to increment a register by one. Handling carry for values larger then 1 byte is your responsibility. For displaying on LCD that value will have to be converted to a string.

Comment: I'm still a noob. So how can i increment the value of a register then convert to string ?

Answer (score 0):

Converting a single (value 0-xff, or 0-255 decimal) to an ASCII string ("255", or hex 0x32 0x35 0x35) can be done in a number of ways ranging from lookup tables (if you have a lot of extra ROM space, and no other types of "printing" requirements), to efficient routines involving bit shifts and masking. Some google searching will get you several options.

You will need to make some decisions about whether you want to display leading zeroes or not, and if you want left-padding with spaces if there are less than 3 digits in the number.

The INCF instruction will just roll over from 255 to 0, which may not be what you want.

Are you sure that you won't be counting higher than 255? If so, you need to use a 16-bit register (0-65535) or 32-bit (0-4294967295).